# Hot Surface Ignitor does not glow

Tags: wiring, hvac

I bought Ecobee Lite thermostat last summer and connected it properly to the furnace using C wire. Air conditioner worked without any issues. But no luck with the heat. When the furnace gets the call from thermostat the exhaust fan starts but no glowing on HSI. Asked my neighbor (HVAC certified) to take a look into this problem. He measured all voltages and resistance but did not give me any answers. Installed the jumper between R and W wires and furnace gets heat right away. After he installed the brand new thermostat with C wire - no luck.
I called another tech and he said my thermostat (Ecobee) is broken. He installed the thermostat( simple one with batteries inside) without C wire (Rh and Rc have jumper) and furnace has heat. So I realized, before I switched to Ecobee my old LUX thermostat was operated without C wire.
The furnace is 19 years old and the brand is HEIL.

Can someone give me some directions how to trace the problem? 
Would be possible even to resolve the issue and use smart thermostat?

I tried to eliminate C wire and even installed ecobee with the PEK - no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: There's something wrong with your description because you would never put a jumper between R and C (Rc is not the C wire).  That would be shorting out the transformer which would either blow a low voltage fuse or eventually cause the transformer to fail.  A call for heat is _typically_ R connected to G for the fan and R connected to W for heat.

Comment: You can [edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/178290/edit) your question to clear up any confusion.  Unless you call for the fan and heat, there could be a pressure sensor that doesn't allow the ignition to begin.

Comment: I edited my question as you suggested. Why is pressure sensor works when thermostat is not connected to C wire?

Comment: It could be that the "C" wire isn't properly wired.  Since the system works with a "dumb" thermostat, the C wire could be wrong, or there could be a software setting on the ecobee to select the correct type of heating system.  For instance, if it was accidentally set up for a heat pump application, it might not work properly with a standard furnace.

Comment: "C" wire goes directly to C terminal on the board. Even I sent pictures to Ecobee tech support person and we verified that thermostat wired properly. The second brand new thermostat (not the smart one) that requires C wire does not work either. I will get home and measure the voltage between C and R terminals on the board, resistance between the C terminal and other ground point and visually inspect the preasure switch.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also try to find the trouble LED on the control board for the furnace.  There will be a blinking LED or a number display to show you errors in some cases.

Comment: Suspects: poor voltage; undersized thermostat wire or under performing transformer. Possibly: intermittent or dying sensor adding too much resistance to the safety circuit which cannot be overcome when a T-stat is stealing power. Google: model number of 19yo unit + eccobee + 'doesn't work'.

Comment: No trouble LED on this board. 28 V between R and C terminals. Visually inspected pressure switch and did not find any cracks on the hose connected to inducer motor. To Mazura comment regarding undersized wire - I installed brand new thermostat electrical cable 18/5. One thing that I noticed - the exhaust from furnace vent is not strong compare to the water tank exhaust. These two are side by side and have approximate the same exhaust vent pipe length. I will inspect the exhaust pipe on the weekend to make sure it;s not clogged

Comment: I did not expect the outcome but the furnace is working with the smart thermostat. I am not sure why but it takes 5 min in average to start heating after the induce motor is being activated compare to old thermostat when gas is being ignited right away when the call received from thermostat. Any ideas?